# Undefined function 'squareform' for input arguments of type 'double'

Tags: matlab

I have a matrix `W`, in Matlab which is of type `double` and upon trying to run `W_sf=squareform(W)';` I get the following error:

```
Undefined function 'squareform' for input arguments of type 'double'.
```

I tried running `squareform` after converting `W` to float using `single(W)`, and I still get the same error with `squareform`. What is the exact type that I must convert `W` into, and how?

Comment: Do you have the Statistics Toolbox? Can you type `help squareform` in the command window? And what version of Matlab are you using?

Comment: You were right. The statistics toolbox 'trial' had expired and hence, the unexpected behavior.